# Advice added using ByteBuddy AgentBuilder is not getting invoked

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I am trying to add a advice in my application so that the onEnter and onExit gets called when a method CassandraFunctions.loadObjectByKey is invoked during execution flow. I used below code to register a advice.

```
protected void instrument(boolean t) {

    Instrumentation instrument = null;
    // Get loader initialized in premain class
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("my.loader.InstrumentLoader");
        java.lang.reflect.Method m = c.getMethod("getInstrument");
        instrument = (Instrumentation) m.invoke(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(instrument == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Add an advice 
    String clzName = CassandraFunctionsAdvice.class.getName();
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
.with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
.type(ElementMatchers.named("my.functions.CassandraFunctions"))
        .transform( 
                new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                    .include(Class.class.getClassLoader())
                    .advice(ElementMatchers.named("loadObjectByKey"), clzName))
        .installOn(instrument);
}
```

And the advice class looks like below:

```
public class CassandraFunctionsAdvice {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void onEnter(@Advice.Argument(0) String key) {

        String debugText = "OnMethodEnter|loadObjectByKey|key=" + key;
        System.out.println(debugText);
    }

    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    public static void onExit(@Advice.Thrown Throwable throwable) {
        String debugText = "OnMethodExit|loadObjectByKey";
        System.out.println(debugText);
    }
}
```

The class that is being instrumented looks like below:

```
public class CassandraFunctions {
    public static Object loadObjectByKey(String key) {
        ....
        return object;
    }
}
```

The instrumented class my.functions.CassandraFunctions is loaded much before the function loadObjectByKey is called on a user request. I am not sure what is missing and why the advice is not getting invoked.

Comment: And what is `my.loader.InstrumentLoader` doing? As you have a statement like `if(instrument == null) { return; }` that returns silently, did you check that this is not happening? As `CassandraFunctionsAdvice.class` may already cause the loading of dependent classes, is *retransformation* enabled?

Comment: `my.loader.InstrumentLoader` is Premain-Class and keeps a reference of Instrumentation. And yes I verified that I get a reference of Instrumentation, its not silently returning. I tried by enabling retransformation and setting `AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION`, but still advice isn't called. BTW, as you see, I am not doing much in `CassandraFunctionsAdvice.class` as of now.

Comment: I’m puzzled by the line `include(Class.class.getClassLoader())`. The loader of `Class.class` is the bootstrap loader.

Comment: I tried to use different class loaders to see if it resolves the issue. I tried `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`, `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` with no success, hence used `Class.class.getClassLoader()`. But the issue seems to be something different.

Comment: Too many variables here. Could you please condense your setup into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally a Maven project on GitHub, so we all can see the interplay of Java agent, ByteBuddy code, application and classloaders? I am quite confident that if someone can reproduce the problem, you will get a spot-on answer quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already answered your question [on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/1005):

The advice code is just a template. The private field is not visible to the code once it is inlined by Byte Buddy.

The question you need to ask yourself is: Could I copy-paste this code to the target class and would it still compile? If no, then you need to change your advice. If you want to manage shared state, you would need to move it to a class that is accessible to the class loader(s) in question and inject it into an appropriate location.

Comment: This is why I asked for an MCVE here. The sample code in the question does not contain any private fields in the advice and nowhere was there a link to the GitHub issue. So this answer correctly solves the problem as presented on GitHub after in the second iteration the OP showed the necessary details of his use case. But technically, it does not fit the sample code here. This is a perfect example why pseudo code is so misleading and incomplete code so unhelpful.